# Using shell environment variables in Apache configuration conditional statements?

Tags: apache, apache2

I am unclear on whether I can have a variable such as

```
LAN_ALIAS=some.local.domain
```

in my shell environment, and conditionally use it to generate a ServerAlias directive:

```
<MagicalIfEnvVar LAN_ALIAS>
  ServerAlias ${LAN_ALIAS}
</MagicalIfEnvVar>
```

I've been reading through the Apache documentation, but as you can imagine, searching on "environment variables" (and variations thereof) leads to a lot of unhelpful references.

Any way to do something like that in Apache2.2?